# How can I change the color of the rectangle in the overview map (Google Maps v3)?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I try to change the color of the blue rectangle in the Google Maps overview map (in the lower right area of the Google Maps window). 
Unfortunately, in the documentation for Google Maps v3 nothing is said about that.
Do you have an idea?

Comment: overvieMap is a small map inside the map(in the bottom-right corner) when enabled.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle - If you have activated the overview map in the lower right area of the Google Maps window, you see the current large map there with a rectangle. This is the rectangle that I want to colorize - default it is blue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to colorize there anything via the API.

What you can do: use JS to find the elements and then use CSS to apply the colors.

Example:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'tilesloaded',function()
        {
          try{
            var x=document.querySelector('img[src=\'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mapcontrols3d7.png\']');
            if(x)
            {
              x.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.className="overviewMap";
              var y=document.querySelectorAll('.overviewMap>div>div>div>div>div>div');
              y[1].className="overviewMapRectangle";
            }
          }catch(e){}
        }
        );
```

The only thing that seems to be unique there is an image(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mapcontrols3d7.png), it's the arrow used to open/close the overviewMap. The script searches for that image and walks trough the DOM to find the rectangle. It will add a class to the rectangle(overviewMapRectangle) which may be used as selector.

Sample-CSS:

```
.overviewMapRectangle + div > div{border:none !important}
.overviewMapRectangle div{border-color: inherit !important}
/*border-color of the rectangle*/
.overviewMapRectangle{border-color: yellow !important}    
/*background-color of the rectangle*/
.overviewMapRectangle>div>div{background: red !important}
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ULmW5/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ULmW5/)

The problem: google may change the DOM for the Maps tomorrow and it will not work anymore.